# npm force package-lock to update a sub-dependency package

Tags: npm, package.json

Due to some code vulnerability, I am trying to update a sub-dependency. The package is [`snapdragon`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/snapdragon), currently I have the version 0.8.2 installed, but I wish to upgrade to the latest `0.12.0`.

I have updated all the packages that require `snapdragon` as a dependency. Now according to those packages package.json they require `"^0.8.1"` which should namely support `0.12.0` as well.

Here's the result of `npm ls snapdragon`:

```
├─┬ nodemon@1.19.2
│ └─┬ chokidar@2.1.8
│   └─┬ braces@2.3.2
│     └── snapdragon@0.8.2  deduped
└─┬ webpack@4.40.2
  └─┬ micromatch@3.1.10
    ├─┬ extglob@2.0.4
    │ ├─┬ expand-brackets@2.1.4
    │ │ └── snapdragon@0.8.2  deduped
    │ └── snapdragon@0.8.2  deduped
    ├─┬ nanomatch@1.2.13
    │ └── snapdragon@0.8.2  deduped
    └── snapdragon@0.8.2
```

I have tried running `npm update snapdragon`, I have also tried a fresh `npm install` with no package-lock but with no luck. Eventually, I decided to forcibly install `snapdraon@0.12.0` but now it seems I have unmet dependencies.

```
├─┬ nodemon@1.19.2
│ └─┬ chokidar@2.1.8
│   └─┬ braces@2.3.2
│     └── UNMET DEPENDENCY snapdragon@^0.8.1
├── snapdragon@0.12.0 
└─┬ webpack@4.40.2
  └─┬ micromatch@3.1.10
    ├─┬ extglob@2.0.4
    │ ├─┬ expand-brackets@2.1.4
    │ │ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY snapdragon@^0.8.1
    │ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY snapdragon@^0.8.1
    ├─┬ nanomatch@1.2.13
    │ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY snapdragon@^0.8.1
    └── UNMET DEPENDENCY snapdragon@^0.8.1
```

Shouldn't the requirement `^0.8.1` accept version `0.12.0`? How can I instruct package-lock to update the package to the latest version?

Comment: Have you tried installing Snapdragon from scratch?

Comment: @SachinYadav yep, and even the entire list of dependencies with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't answer the carret question, but on the topic of the header (forcing npm to update a sub-dependency), we had a simillar issue with `puppeteer > extract-zip > mkdirp > minimist`, where `minimist`  had a security vulnerability.    It was upgraded and so was `mkdirp` , but `extract-zip` isn't at the time of this writting.

Using `npx npm-force-resolutions` under the `scripts` entry in `package.json` seems to have solved (albeit not ideally) the vulnerability

```
$ git diff package.json 
diff --git a/package.json b/package.json
index cf825cf..0d694b3 100644
--- a/package.json
+++ b/package.json
@@ -8,8 +8,13 @@
     "lib": "lib" 
   },
   "scripts": {
+    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions",
     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1" 
   },
+  "resolutions": {
+    "minimist": "1.2.3",
+    "mkdir": "0.5.3" 
+  },
```

Then running `npm install`:

```
$ npm install && npm audit

> sge@1.0.0 preinstall /home/jlam/code/prjName
> npx npm-force-resolutions

npx : 5 installé(s) en 5.733s
added 1 package from 1 contributor, removed 1 package and audited 72 packages in 7.212s

[...]


found 0 vulnerabilities
[...]

                       === npm audit security report ===                        

found 0 vulnerabilities
 in 72 scanned packages
```

Comment: Thanks @Julien Lamarche. Using your solution I solved the problem. Marco

Comment: when there is no package-lock.json available, npx npm-force-resolutions on pre-install will return an error

Comment: @AmamMustofa How do we use force resolution without a package-lock.json?

Comment: @Automator npm install supposedly works by writing package-lock.json and installing packages in node-modules right?, means that using npm-force-resolution is not doing what npm install does imo

Answer (score 0):

I did this and still get the same errors as before. Why? I'm very new to this.

```
found 1 low severity vulnerability in 3522 scanned packages
  1 vulnerability requires manual review. See the full report for details.
➜  web-dev-starter git:(master) ✗ npx npm-force-resolutions
npx: installed 5 in 1.27s
➜  web-dev-starter git:(master) ✗ npm install
audited 3522 packages in 1.712s

2 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
➜  web-dev-starter git:(master) ✗ npm fund
js-starter-code@1.0.0
├─┬ https://github.com/sponsors/isaacs
│ └── glob@7.1.6
└─┬ https://github.com/sponsors/ljharb
  └── resolve@1.15.1

➜  web-dev-starter git:(master) ✗
```

I don't know who these people or this git hub is. Do I have to join a membership to get the code? What is this?

Comment: Hi Brad, awesome that you trying out the answers and sharing results of that, shows you really trying and that really makes the difference :) 

What can help even more, for you and the community, is to create a new post/question and link to this one. Keeps it simple, especially since your source code might be 'similar' but not exact, so everyone answering the same problem here :)

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you fr the help, I'll try that. It's very very hard getting it to accept my question. I don't understand enough javaScript yet to use the right words i guess?

Comment: Hi Brad, a great thing to do as your learning the basics is just keep looking for other people asking or answering the same question :) If your self-learning coding on your own, so many awesome and free tutorial websites that can help you break it down to the basics. For anything with NodeJS especially there such an awesome and evolving community. Just try the next tutorial, or find a site that maybe describes it just a little differently. I know all the npm stuff was a bit overwhelming for me at the start too, plus learning js at same time ;) But its all simple steps, just one step at a time.

Comment: I need help. I don't understand how to ask questions on this site. my questions arn't accepted by the validation because they don't use the right words? someone said they can't read my questions because they code is not indented? Now the site won't let me post a termincal error for over an hour because it says there is only code but i've asked a question? Nothing is working.

Comment: Hi rvakid, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and more importantly decently ranked questions (bounties section might be good place to look). Describe in text in question body your desired outcome vs current outcome, the context (meaning your app language, purpose of your app. Adding any other context details in as much detail as possible usually helps) and exactly what you tried already, including enough source code + context for someone to reproduce your problem. At bare minimum you have to show you tried, share code + description and be clear what you trying to achieve.

Comment: HI Daniel, Thank you. I did read that but I don't understand what it wants me to do. I don't understand the programing language to have an outcome, I literally don't understand a word of it. All I'm trying to do is follow an entry level tutorial for JavaScript. I don't know what the correct outcome is, i need someone to help with that. Where else can I ask? Is there a programing language for stack overflow I should learn first? Is stackoverflow just for professionals and not students? OK if so.

Comment: Hi Rvakid, just keep doing those tutorials, if one is too hard to understand, find another that describes it better. I can also bet you any amount of money that any questions you have along the way at this point, they been answered before many times, especially if your following entry level tutorials, so dont worry too much at this point, just keep going :)